# Uploading a file to storage location

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm getting stuck on uploading a file via the data management API to a BIM 360 storage location, specifically the last step I've been following the step by step guide on the forge site [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) and saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595030/how-to-upload-file-to-storage-location-in-autodesk-forge-using-3-legged-token/41599062#41599062?newreg=7de68cfb63004972b3f8359ba10a4a39) however using postman copying and pasting it gets stuck on the final step "update the version of the file" every other step returns correctly however the last one gives me an error 400 BAD_INPUT response, not sure how to format the code and response so i just hosted it [here](http://freetexthost.com/3h2b2evrez)

any help will be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested with the BIM360 storage location, and it works good to me, there are a couple of issues you may need to keep in mind as follow:

1. Since you are using BIM360 hub, so when you try to create the first version of the uploaded file as you described, please use the correct extension type in the POST body, for BIM360, should be items:autodesk.bim360:File and versions:autodesk.bim360:File as follow:

[image]

2. When you try to create a storage under a folder using  POST projects/:project_id/storage, in the POST body, you need to specify the folder, please make sure to use the correct folder that allow types of "items:autodesk.bim360:File", for example, the following folder is the root folder of my project, and it only allow the folder of "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder", if you create a storage under this folder, you will get 403 forbid error.
   [image]

But this folder should be Ok:
[image]

Comment: Yes! it was your first point, i tried in both root and specific folder with no luck, it was changing it to "items:autodesk.bim360:File" that did the trick! Thank you very much for your help :)